# GRPC custom codec for measuring compression/decompression times

Tags: go, compression, grpc, codec

I want to measure the cost/time of compressing and decompressing the payloads handled by the GRPC library. I've created some functions that I believe will give me reasonably accurate timings (see `MeasureTimeAndCpu`) for this to occur and from what I have read I need to create my own codec, wrapping the default `proto` codec so that I can 'override' the Marshal/Unmarshal functions:

```golang
package codec

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "google.golang.org/grpc/encoding"
    "log"
    "my/json-over-grpc/pkg/metrics"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("registering custom codec")
    encoding.RegisterCodec(&TimerCodec{
        encoding.GetCodec("proto"),
    })
}

type TimerCodec struct {
    encoding.Codec
}

func (g *TimerCodec) Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
        fmt.Println("g.codec ", g.Codec)
        return g.Codec.Marshal(v)
}

func (g *TimerCodec) Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error {
    fmt.Println("unmarshalling")
    // Check if the data is compressed with gzip
    if len(data) >= 2 && data[0] == 0x1f && data[1] == 0x8b {
        var err error
        startTime, startCpuTime := metrics.MeasureTimeAndCpu(func() {
            var reader *gzip.Reader
            reader, err = gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            defer reader.Close()
            uncompressed, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
            data = uncompressed
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        log.Printf("Decompression wall time: %d, CPU time: %d", startTime, startCpuTime)
    }

    return g.Codec.Unmarshal(data, v)
}

func (g *TimerCodec) Name() string {
    return "mytimercodec" // use a unique name for your codec
}
```

In my server then I am doing

```golang
    cdc := &codec.TimerCodec{
        Codec: encoding.GetCodec("proto"),
    }
    encoding.RegisterCodec(cdc)
```

and on my client I'm doing

```golang
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(":10000",
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.CallContentSubtype("mytimercodec")),
    )
```

and I've also tried in when making the call in the client to do

```golang
    opts := []grpc.CallOption{
        grpc.CallContentSubtype((&codec.TimerCodec{
            Codec: encoding.GetCodec("proto"),
        }).Name()), // Use TimerCodec for message transmission
    }
```

but what I keep facing on the client side is `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` coming from the line `return g.Codec.Marshal(v)` in the marshal function in my custom codec, i.e `g.Codec` is `nil`.

I'm struggling to find the docs surrounding the way to do this so I suspect I am slightly off somewhere or whether there may even be a simpler way to do this...
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proto" codec never gets registered, so `encoding.GetCodec("proto")` always returns `nil`. [encoding/proto/proto.go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/v1.55.0/encoding/proto/proto.go) registers this codec in its own `init()` function, so you need to make sure this subpackage gets loaded.

Based on the way the package is organized, I suggest:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/grpc/encoding"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/encoding/proto"
)

func init() {
    encoding.RegisterCodec(&TimerCodec{
        encoding.GetCodec(proto.Name),
    })
}

type TimerCodec struct {
    encoding.Codec
}
```

However, you should use probably use the built-in Go Benchmarking library instead of writing your own timing logic: https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks

Comment: ahhh thanks! I'll try that!
re benchmarking, the call to Marshal/Unmarshal happens "behind the scenes" - how can I use benchmarking library to measure this time? I realise I can use it to make the full GRPC request and measure the round trip time etc.
I am wanting the timings sent off to a logging server, not just for testing purposes? Any tips appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! Can you mark this as the correct answer? :) Can you clarify the problem you're trying to solve here? The code you have in `MeasureTimeAndCpu` looks like something you can easily put into a separate function, benchmark for different inputs, and draw conclusions about its performance in a live system. You can also call any functions you like in a benchmark test, including `Marshal` and `Unmarshal`.

Comment: so im trying to as you say create benchmarks of the wall/cpu time to transfer data when its compressed/not compressed and the wall/cpu time of doing the compression/decompression and marshalling for sending the data. 
However i also want to be able, in production to turn these on/off and record/send to log server these metrics (in some cases the data is small that compression is a cost not a benefit etc).
Hard to find a good example/implementation of doing this with go/GRPC and how the codecs/compressors/stats and interceptors can help me, so any help really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I just don't understand why you're trying to do it. :) Aren't all of the operations you're trying to time O(1) or O(n) such that you can predict their performance a priori, or at least infer their performance in production from local benchmarks without needing cumbersome monitoring?

Comment: hmm well the short answer is it was requested lol, but i see your point. gzip is gzip and data over the wire is data over the wire... I guess the interest is if we can work out in real time whether we should gzip a specific payload as opposed to not, if its not going to improve the request speed.

Comment: Are you sure gRPC can't be configured to make that choice automatically?

Comment: hmm i hadn't thought about that, so no. I don't find the more 'advanced' capabilities of GRPC very easy to find documentation around (beyond the go pkg docs).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253808/discussion-between-spencer-connaughton-and-amlwwalker).